# why the function in flutter calling infinitely?

Tags: flutter, function, dart

I'm new in flutter. I'm calling a login API on button click. The API code is written in a function which is below.

My problem is that this function is calling infinitely after clicking on button at a time only.

```
      Future<Login?> logins() async {
        print("login function called");
        String uemail = emailText.text;
        String upassword = passwordText.text;

        print("Email: $uemail, Pass: $upassword");

        if (uemail.isEmpty || uemail == null) {
          print('enter your email');
        } else if (upassword.isEmpty || upassword == null) {
          print('enter your password');
        } else {
          Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.29.248:5000/login");
          var json_body = {'email': uemail, 'password': upassword};

          var response = await http.post(myUri, body: json_body);
          print('response code ' + response.statusCode.toString());
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var res = json.decode(response.body);
            print('response res' + res.toString());
            login = Login.fromJson(res);
            if (login?.success == 0) {
              print('enter email');
            } else if (login?.success == 2) {
              print('enter password');
            } else if (login?.success == 1) {
              print('login success');
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
            }
          }
          return logins();
        }
      }
```

Please view my code and provide the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are retuning(calling) the function `return logins();`

It is known as recursive function.

based on your code it will be

```dart
return login;
```

Comment: Thanks @Yeasin sheikh , it is working now.

Comment: Glad to help, you can search more about `recursive function`, it has many useful case.